# Request timed out when deployed nodejs server online

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, fetch-api

I have two parts of this code, I am not sure where the error comes from or how to diagnose it, my code works fine on my localhost and returns the data correctly and it shows up on my front end without issue.

When I deployed the server to render.com (free plan) I got this issue

> [Error: The request timed out.]

I tried fixing the root of the server like so:

```
const server =  app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Running server at port: ${port}`);
});

server.setTimeout(120000); // 120 seconds timeout
```

Then on the API endpoint there's two functions, added axios timeout functionality because of the issue, for ffmepg I am not sure how to fix it

```
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  var videoUrl = req.body.video;

  const videoResponse = await axios.get(videoUrl, {
    responseType: 'arraybuffer',
  });

  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', Buffer.from(videoResponse.data), {
    filename: 'video.mp4',
  });
  formData.append('model', model);
  formData.append('response_format', 'srt');

  const headers = {
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
    ...formData.getHeaders(),
  };

  const response = await axios.post('https://example.com', formData, {
    headers,
      timeout: 1200000
  });

  fs.writeFileSync('transcription.srt', response.data);
  console.log('Transcription saved to transcription.srt');

  const subtitlePath = "./transcription.srt";
  console.log('subtitlePath :', subtitlePath);

  const randomNum = Math.floor(100000000000 + Math.random() * 900000000000);
  const fileName = `video_${randomNum}.mp4`;
  const outputPath = `./${fileName}`;

  // Execute the ffmpeg command to burn the subtitles into the video
  const ffmpeg = spawn("ffmpeg", [
    "-i",
    "pipe:0",
    "-vf",
    `subtitles=${subtitlePath}:force_style='Alignment=10,OutlineColour=&H100000000,BorderStyle=3,Outline=1,Shadow=0,Fontsize=10'`,
    "-c:a",
    "copy",
    "-progress", "pipe:1",
    outputPath,
  ]);

  // Pipe the videoResponse array buffer to FFmpeg
  ffmpeg.stdin.write(videoResponse.data);
  ffmpeg.stdin.end();

  // Send the output file as a response once the process is complete
  ffmpeg.on("close", () => {
    fs.readFile(outputPath, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).send("Failed to read the file");
      } else {
        res.set({
          "Content-Disposition": `attachment; filename=${outputPath}`,
          "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
        });
        res.send(data);
        console.log("File sent successfully");
        // Delete the output file once it has been sent
        fs.unlinkSync(outputPath);
      }
    });
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

On my react native app, I added promise and some timeout code just to make sure the error it's not originated from there but still facing the same issue

```
testing = (downloadURL) => {
    const timeoutPromise = new Promise((_, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        reject(new Error('Request timed out'));
      }, 120000); // 120 seconds timeout
    });

    this.setState({ loading: true, uploading: false });
    RNFetchBlob.config({
      fileCache: true,
      appendExt: 'mp4',
    })
      .fetch('POST', 'https://example.com/api/v1/test', {
        'Accept': 'application/octet-stream',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }, JSON.stringify({
        video: downloadURL,
      }))
      .then(response => {
        const videoPath = response.path();
        const videoUrl = `file://${videoPath}`;
        console.log('videoUrl :', videoUrl);
        this.setState({ loading: false, success: true, render: videoUrl, downloadURL: null });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        this.setState({
          error: error.message,
          loading: false,
        });
      })
      .finally(() => {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
      });

    const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Request timed out');
      this.setState({
        error: 'Request timed out',
        loading: false,
      });
    }, 120000); // 120 seconds timeout

    Promise.race([timeoutPromise])
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        this.setState({
          error: error.message,
          loading: false,
        });
      });
  };
```

Now to describe the problem, after triggering the endpoint the api is running fine then start the axios post request, this part is very fast and get done in about 2-3 seconds, the file then is moved to ffmpeg for converting, I have another piece of code that allows me to check conversion status progress, usually from what I see is when percentage is about to hit 100% I got the error timed out on my fronend and on the server it shows

> POST /api/v1/test - - ms - -

**No error on console log whatesover**

Please help. Any suggestions appreciated

Those are logs from the server deployed

```
Apr 24 02:22:23 AM  POST /api/v1/test - - ms - -
Apr 24 02:22:23 AM  FFmpeg     : 100%
Apr 24 02:22:24 AM  FFmpeg     : 100%
Apr 24 02:22:24 AM  FFmpeg     : 100%
Apr 24 02:22:26 AM  FFmpeg     : 100%
Apr 24 02:22:26 AM  FFmpeg     : 100%
Apr 24 02:22:27 AM  FFmpeg     : 100%
Apr 24 02:22:29 AM  FFmpeg     : 100%
Apr 24 02:22:29 AM  FFmpeg     : 100%
Apr 24 02:22:30 AM  FFmpeg     : 100%
Apr 24 02:22:31 AM  FFmpeg     : 100%
Apr 24 02:22:32 AM  FFmpeg     : 100%
Apr 24 02:22:33 AM  FFmpeg     : 100%
Apr 24 02:22:34 AM  FFmpeg     : 100%
Apr 24 02:22:35 AM  FFmpeg     : 100%
Apr 24 02:22:36 AM  FFmpeg     : 100%
Apr 24 02:22:36 AM  FFmpeg     : 100%
Apr 24 02:22:37 AM  FFmpeg     : 100%
Apr 24 02:22:38 AM  FFmpeg     : 100%
Apr 24 02:22:38 AM  FFmpeg     : 100%
Apr 24 02:22:39 AM  FFmpeg     : 100%
Apr 24 02:22:39 AM  FFmpeg     : 100%
Apr 24 02:22:40 AM  FFmpeg     : 100%
Apr 24 02:22:41 AM  FFmpeg     : 100%
Apr 24 02:22:53 AM  FFmpeg     : 100%
Apr 24 02:22:53 AM  File sent successfully
```

Answer (score -1):

I'll just axios next time, fixed the issue right away, that fetch native module is horrible

Comment: It's probably less horrible if you use it as intended... `fetch(url, { method: "POST", headers: { ... } })`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API